# Hyperparameter optimization for ANN keras model using genetic algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I want to use GASearchCV from sklearn_genetic library to optimize hyperparameters my keras model. First I defined a function to build my model. Then I used scikeras to create my estimator. Finally I called GASearchCV to optimize hyperparameter and then fitted it on data. The codes are here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
from sklearn_genetic import GASearchCV
from sklearn_genetic.space import Categorical, Integer

def ann_model_ga(number_of_hidden_layer=1,
                 number_of_neurons=50,
                 optimizer="adam"):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
    for hidden_layer in range(number_of_hidden_layer):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(number_of_neurons))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy", "AUC"],)
    return model

param_grid = {'number_of_hidden_layer': Integer(1, 5),
              'number_of_neurons': Integer(100, 200),
              'optimizer': Categorical(["adam", "sgd"])}

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=ann_model_ga)

evolved_estimator = GASearchCV(estimator=estimator,
                               cv=5,
                               scoring='accuracy',
                               population_size=10,
                               generations=35,
                               tournament_size=3,
                               elitism=True,
                               crossover_probability=0.8,
                               mutation_probability=0.1,
                               param_grid=param_grid,
                               criteria='max',
                               algorithm='eaMuPlusLambda',
                               n_jobs=-1,
                               verbose=True,
                               keep_top_k=4)
history_ga = evolved_estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-36285fd9a509> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history_ga = evolved_estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py in set_params(self, **params)
   1163                     # Give a SciKeras specific user message to aid
   1164                     # in moving from the Keras wrappers
-> 1165                     raise ValueError(
   1166                         f"Invalid parameter {param} for estimator {self.__name__}."
   1167                         "\nThis issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter"

ValueError: Invalid parameter number_of_hidden_layer for estimator KerasClassifier.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasClassifier constructor:
`KerasClassifier(number_of_hidden_layer=1)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`
```

Can any body help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem using scikit_learn's GASearchCV() to optimise the hypaparameters of a TensorFlow RNN. I kept coming up against errors that I could not resolve, some like yours which made no sense. In the end my research pointed to the fact that GASearchCV() does not work with a TensorFLow NN (although this would need to verfied).

In the end I opted to use PyGad's genetic algorythum to do the job. It doesn't help with your code, but if you are still having trouble it could be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to a mismatch between the parameter names in your ann_model_ga function and the parameter names in the param_grid dictionary. The GASearchCV is trying to pass the number_of_hidden_layer parameter to the KerasClassifier, but it does not recognize this parameter.

To resolve this issue, you need to update the parameter names in your ann_model_ga function to match the keys in the param_grid dictionary. Here's the modified code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
from sklearn_genetic import GASearchCV
from sklearn_genetic.space import Categorical, Integer

def ann_model_ga(number_of_hidden_layers=1,
                 number_of_neurons=50,
                 optimizer="adam"):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
    for _ in range(number_of_hidden_layers):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(number_of_neurons))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy", "AUC"],)
    return model

param_grid = {'number_of_hidden_layers': Integer(1, 5),
              'number_of_neurons': Integer(100, 200),
              'optimizer': Categorical(["adam", "sgd"])}

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=ann_model_ga)

evolved_estimator = GASearchCV(estimator=estimator,
                               cv=5,
                               scoring='accuracy',
                               population_size=10,
                               generations=35,
                               tournament_size=3,
                               elitism=True,
                               crossover_probability=0.8,
                               mutation_probability=0.1,
                               param_grid=param_grid,
                               criteria='max',
                               algorithm='eaMuPlusLambda',
                               n_jobs=-1,
                               verbose=True,
                               keep_top_k=4)
history_ga = evolved_estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Note the changes in the function parameter names from number_of_hidden_layer to number_of_hidden_layers in the ann_model_ga function definition.

By making this change, the GASearchCV will be able to pass the correct parameter names to the KerasClassifier and resolve the error you encountered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it didn't help and I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'model__' before params that get the error.

```
`param_grid = {'model__number_of_hidden_layers': Integer(1, 5),
          'model__number_of_neurons': Integer(100, 200),
          'optimizer': Categorical(["adam", "sgd"])}

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=ann_model_ga)`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).